# Subscribe to raydium swaps

Tags: web3.js, raydium

I search for a way to subscribe to all swap transactions of the Raydium program.

I have the following code:

```
rpcClient.onProgramAccountChange(
    RAYDIUM_PROGRAM_ID,
    async (keyedAccountInfo, context) => {

        // some filters here...

        const data = AccountLayout.decode(keyedAccountInfo.accountInfo.data);

        console.log(data);
    },
    "confirmed"
);
```

Which works actually perfect but the `data` isn't really useful for me. It's something like:

```
{
  mint: PublicKey [PublicKey(QRSsyMWN1ygcBMa6gUWN3FaeU7XXZvXFXCzWdV3Y6s1)] {
    _bn: <BN: 600000000000000fe0000000000000007000000000000000300000000000000>
  },
  owner: PublicKey [PublicKey(c8fpTXm3XTSVpAViQ9cBdT5ofwpgDmCcrHZSrxqx1Ku)] {
    _bn: <BN: 900000000000000090000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000>
  },
  amount: 1000000n,
  delegateOption: 500,
  delegate: PublicKey [PublicKey(1111fMZ2jEB1YFgdJbBdN74ZFceZtdNbBdfCv8z9Cj)] {
    _bn: <BN: 404b4c000000000040420f000000000040420f000000000001000000>
  },
  state: 0,
  isNativeOption: 0,
  isNative: 3906250n,
  delegatedAmount: 360287970193545930n,
  closeAuthorityOption: 0,
  closeAuthority: PublicKey [PublicKey(111jXiRDaJNN6qCmxVFDzasv5SRRn7JA2VskN1jx4f)] {
    _bn: <BN: 1027000000000000190000000000000010270000000000000c00000000>
  }
}
```

It seems like that `onProgramAccountChange` just informs me about the swap event but does not provide any data related to the swap (e.g. amountIn, amountOut). Also a signature isn't present, otherwise I could fetch additional data afterwards.

Does someone has an idea how I can receive additional data about the swap event?